# Ampersand converted into %26 in url

Tags: django, solr

I'm trying to put/concatenate in the url, once a form is submitted, the q and/or the fq from a search query. This is the code I have tried so far:

```
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ content.params.q }}'{% verbatim %}&type={% endverbatim %}'{{request.GET.type}}" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ content.params.q }}&type{{request.GET.type}}" />
```

I also tried with

```
{% autoescape on %}
```

to no avail. Basically I want the final url (i.e. what is in the address bar after the form is submitted) to be something like

```
q=something&somethingelse
```

Instead, I get

```
q=something%26type%3Dsomethingelse
```

How can I get the template to output ampersand and equals as they are without being encoded into %?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I used javascript for this.

```
<form role = "form" id="filter" action="/search/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="something" id="something" ...>
```

[...]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filter").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();       
        $this = $(this);
        var something = $('#something').val();

        var qstr = window.location.search;
        var url = qstr + '&something=' + something;
        };
        window.location.search = url;
    });
});
```